# Does Flurry have an HTML5 SDK?

Tags: javascript, flurry, flurry-analytics

Looking at [Yahoo's documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/ios/) I can only see Android and iOS mentioned.

I have found several articles about a JS SDK, and I've even found a script : https://cdn.flurry.com/js/flurry.js

Does anyone know if this is old / being discontinued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we still have an HTML sdk. Just create a new project and choose mobile web as the project type. The documentation is in the readme files. Currently we only provide limited support for this sdk but I don't have an indication it will be discontinued.

Comment: Is this flurry SDK still active? Where can I find it, along with it documentation?